# Multiple where clause working with OR, not with AND

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all, I'm not an SQL expert, so probably I'm missing some brackets or something else that's stupid simple ;-)

Can anyone please tell me why this works and returns 4 rows:

```
SELECT ppa.products_id FROM products_propattributes ppa 
WHERE ( (options_id = "11" AND options_values_id = "18") 
OR (options_id = "4" AND options_values_id = "4") )
```

And this one doesn't, while it should match 1 row:

```
SELECT ppa.products_id FROM products_propattributes ppa 
WHERE ( (options_id = "11" AND options_values_id = "18") 
AND (options_id = "4" AND options_values_id = "4") )
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance..

Bas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there can only be one possible value in a column in every row. If you want to get the `ID` that has both condition to return true using `OR`

```
SELECT ppa.products_id 
FROM products_propattributes ppa 
WHERE (options_id = "11" AND options_values_id = "18") OR 
      (options_id = "4" AND options_values_id = "4") 
GROUP BY ppa.products_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

In the second query you have only `AND`s, so it's impossible that `options_id = "11"` AND `options_id = "4"` both match.

And of course the same with `options_values_id = "18"` AND `options_values_id = "4"`.

Answer (score 2):

Second query looking for rows where `options_id = "11"` **AND**  `options_id = "4"`. It's not possible because `options_id` column cloud have only one value.